# В VSC не работает функция , при этом не выводится ошибка

Tags: python, discord.py, discord, discord-api

```
from discord.ext import commands, tasks
import os

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True  # Enable member intents
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='*', intents=intents)
base_folder = "base/"

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'Logged in as {bot.user.name}')

@bot.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    file_name = os.path.join(r'D:\ProgrammsVSC\DSbot_2\base',f'{member.name}.txt')  # Абсолютный путь
    with open(file_name, 'w') as file:
        file.write(f'{member.name}\n\'country\':\'Default(по умолчанию)\'')
    print(f'New member: {member.name}')

@tasks.loop(hours=24)
async def update_nicknames():
    for guild in bot.guilds:
        for member in guild.members:
            file_name = base_folder + f'{member.name}.txt'
            with open(file_name, 'w') as file:
                file.write(member.name)
            print(f'Updated member: {member.name}')

@bot.command()
async def create_country(ctx, country_name):
    print(f'Command received: create_country {country_name}')
    
    # Изменение параметра country у пользователя
    member = ctx.author
    member.country = country_name

    # Создание и присвоение роли с названием страны
    guild = ctx.guild
    role_name = country_name
    role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name=role_name)
    if not role:
        role = await guild.create_role(name=role_name)
    await member.add_roles(role)

    # Изменение параметра во второй строке файла
    file_name = os.path.join(base_folder, f'{member.name}.txt')
    with open(file_name, 'r+') as file:
        lines = file.readlines()
        lines[1] = f'\'country\':\'{country_name}\'\n'
        file.seek(0)
        file.writelines(lines)
        file.truncate()

    await ctx.send(f'Country set to {country_name} and role assigned.')

@bot.command()
async def create_valute(ctx, valute_name):
    print(f'Command received: create_valute {valute_name}')
    
    # Изменение параметра valute у пользователя
    member = ctx.author
    member.valute = valute_name

    # Изменение параметра во второй строке файла
    file_name = os.path.join(base_folder, f'{member.name}.txt')
    with open(file_name, 'r+') as file:
        lines = file.readlines()
        lines[2] = f'\'valute\':\'{valute_name}\'\n'
        file.seek(0)
        file.writelines(lines)
        file.truncate()

    embed = discord.Embed(title="Valute Update", description=f"Valute set to {valute_name}.", color=discord.Color.blue())
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)

bot.run('TOKEN')

Код должен сохранять названия при
вызове соответствующих команд в файлы
с названиями ников пользователей , но при этом бот никак не реагирует на команды 
, а VSC не выводит никаких известий о проблеме в виде ошибок (выполнение программы продолжается).
```